# PHP ucwords function issue

Tags: php, function

I need to make a function that reads my variables at the top and fixes the string so that each word in it has a capital letter. The way I'm currently doing it doesn't seem to work. Here is what I have:

```
<?php
$course1 = "advanced web development";
$course2 = "mobile app development";
$course3 = "info systems with business intell";
function fixCourseName($courseName) {
    $courseName = ucwords($courseName);
}

fixCourseName($course1);
echo $course1;
?>
```

Does anyone know what would be causing the output to still be lower case?

Comment: You must `return` the variable, or pass by reference. Though, why not just use `ucwords()` directly, instead of wrapping it in a function - if that's all it does?

Comment: @MasonCox why do you need a separate function. you can use `ucwords` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either pass it by reference, by using the `&` operator in front of the variable when passing it as an argument. This will change the variable you pass through, without having to return it. The variable is then changed in the global scope.

```
function fixCourseName(&$courseName) {
    $courseName = ucwords($courseName);
}
fixCourseName($course1);
echo $course1;
```

- [PHP docs: Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

You can also `return` the new value, but then it must be assigned again.

```
function fixCourseName($courseName) {
    return ucwords($courseName);
}
$course1 = fixCourseName($course1);
echo $course1;
```

The better solution, if the `fixCourseName()` function does nothing more than using `ucwords()`, you might as well just use

```
$course1 = ucwords($course1);
echo $course1;
```

See this [live demo](https://3v4l.org/WfMJB) to see it all in action.

Comment: Or just `echo ucwords($course1)`. Great answer btw.

Comment: Indeed. Just using the same structure as OP is in the original question. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your function gets a copy of the string passed to it and then updates it. If you want to it affect the original variable that's passed to it, you need to pass it **by reference**, by adding a `&`:

```
function fixCourseName(&$courseName) {
    # Here ------------^
    $courseName = ucwords($courseName);
}
```

If your function is just calling `ucwords`, you don't really need it - just call `ucwords` directly:

```
$course1 = ucwords($course1);
```